# Хороший стиль проектирования больших web страниц

Tags: веб-программирование, проектирование

Здравствуйте. Вопрос относительно хорошего стиля проектирования программ.
Занимаюсь разработкой проекта в `JSF2`. У меня есть довольно большая web форма для поиска/обработки данных. Все элементы на форме так или иначе взаимодействуют друг с другом (изменение какого-нибудь инпута влечет изменение другого). Общение между элементами происходит по их ID.

Для повышения читабельности и легкого сопровождения, надо разбросать все по разным файлам, выделив более-менее однородные блоки. И, если это сделать, то тогда получится, что в одном файле будет ссылка на ID элемента из другого файла.

**Вопрос**: правильно ли это с точки зрения хорошего стиля проектирования? Т.е. если логика одного файла ссылается на элементы из другого файла по ID.

И, если нет, то как лучше всего поступить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считаю, что вы на верном пути. Ведь разделять отдельные программные блоки - это и есть хороший стиль программирования, будь то под веб или системное программирование. А взаимодействие блоков - без этого никуда :) Вот к примеру проект на Django - это по сути подключение своих и сторонних приложений и "слияние их воедино" именно таким образом. Конечно, можно впихнуть всю логику в пару-тройку файлов(или вообще в один) - но это ужас ужасный и быдлокодерство ;)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Надеюсь, еще есть кому что-нибудь 
добавить к этому ответу ))

Comment: Видимо, больше некому что-нибудь добавить (((

Comment: А просто добавлять собственно нечего :) По id - т.к. это чаще всего целочисленный тип с индексом в бд, поиск по которому занимает меньше всего времени, тут вопрос скорости и времени обработки. Именно по этим причинам все завязано на id. Распределение по файлам - это как юнит-проектирование, чтобы вам потом можно было бы производить юнит-тестирование, пишите отдельные блоки программы :)

Comment: Ну, все ясно. Спасибо всем за помощь